# compile time substitution in initializer list

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, enums, constexpr

I have a template class which is ensured to basically be only instantiated with 1 of 2 enums. Now I want to set the value of the template parameter in the initializer based on what enum it was instantiated with. Something like this:

```
enum class MyFirstEnum { red, green, orange };
enum class MySecondEnum { blue, yellow, red };

template <class T>
class MyClass
{
    static_assert(
        std::is_same<T, MyFirstEnum>::value || std::is_same<T, MySecondEnum>::value, 
        "Template parameter must be either MyFirstEnum or MySecondEnum"
    );
public:
    MyClass() 
        : value(std::is_same<T, MyFirstEnum>::value ? MyFirstEnum::red : MySecondEnum::blue)
    {
    }
private:
    T value;

}
```

But of course the compiler complains since the types don't match and the ternary is not a compile time replacement. Is there a way to assign the correct value based on the type parameter?

Any help is appreciated. I am limited to c++11

Comment: `value` cannot possibly hold instances of both types (i.e. `MyFirstEnum`, `MySecondEnum`)

Comment: `MyFirstEnum::red` and `MySecondEnum::blue` both have a value of 0, so maybe just use `value(static_cast<T>(0)`, or just `value()` and let the compiler zero-initialize it for you.

Comment: @nakiya Of course that why the ternary is there in the initialized list to fill in the correct type. The code provided won't compile because this is a run-time check but it needs to be a compile time check.

Comment: @JohnSmith: both operands of the ternary `?:` operator must be the same type. Yours are not.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Provided code is only an example my real use case doesn't have that garantie.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes that's is my question how can I assign the correct one at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, `MyFirstEnum::red` and `MySecondEnum::blue` both have a value of 0, so try this:

```
MyClass() 
    : value(static_cast<T>(0))
{
}
```

Or just:

```
MyClass() 
    : value(0)
{
}
```

Or, let the compiler zero-initialize the value for you:

```
MyClass() 
    : value()
{
}
```

On the other hand, if there is no guarantee that the initial value will always be 0, then I would suggest defining a `traits` structure for each `enum` and have them specify the desired default values:

```
enum class MyFirstEnum { red, green, orange };
enum class MySecondEnum { blue, yellow, red };

template<typename T>
struct MyClass_traits
{
};

template<>
struct MyClass_traits<MyFirstEnum>
{
    static const MyFirstEnum initial_value = MyFirstEnum::red;
};

template<>
struct MyClass_traits<MySecondEnum>
{
    static const MySecondEnum initial_value = MySecondEnum::yellow;
};

template <class T, typename traits = MyClass_traits<T> >
class MyClass
{
    static_assert(
        !(std::is_same<T, MyFirstEnum>::value || std::is_same<T, MySecondEnum>::value), 
        "Template parameter must be either MyFirstEnum or MySecondEnum"
    );

public:
    MyClass() 
        : value(traits::initial_value)
    {
    }

private:
    T value;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Remy's recommendation of a traits class.

```
enum class MyFirstEnum { red, green, orange };
enum class MySecondEnum { blue, yellow, red };

template<class T>
struct Traits
{
};

template<>
struct Traits<MyFirstEnum>
{
    static MyFirstEnum default_val() {return MyFirstEnum::red;}
};

template<>
struct Traits<MySecondEnum>
{
    static MySecondEnum default_val() {return MySecondEnum::blue;}
};

template <class T>
class MyClass
{
    static_assert(
        !(std::is_same<T, MyFirstEnum>::value || std::is_same<T, MySecondEnum>::value), 
        "Template parameter must be either MyFirstEnum or MySecondEnum"
    );
public:
    MyClass() 
        : value(Traits<T>::default_val())
    {
    }
private:
    T value;

}
```

Not tested.